# Not able to obtain HTTP Headers with Transfer Mode is Streamed

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5, multipartform-data

I am developing a WCF REST Web Service using IIS 7.5 and .NET 4.5.

The interface file has this declaration:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "PutDataFile", IsOneWay = true)]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "file")]
void PutDataFile(Stream fileContents);
```

The code is this:

```
public void PutDataFile(Stream fileContents)
```

When I perform a Multipart POST from the client, the stream fileContents is this:

```
------------------------------b64bd2de2e40
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadTest.txt"; filename="UploadTest.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

...

------------------------------b64bd2de2e40--
```

However if, on the server side, I do this:

```
String contentType1 = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.ContentType;
String contentType2 = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType];
WebHeaderCollection headers = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
```

All of these variables are null.  I looked at the traffic using WireShark and HTTP Request headers are in the transmission, in particular, the Content-Type header.  Why are those header variables null?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably because this is an OneWay operation. Can you try using this instead to read the headers? var contentType = HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType;
            var headers = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers; Make sure you have the aspnetCompatibility mode turned on in your web.config.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  This is what I ended up using:

String contentType1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType;
String contentType2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Content-Type"];
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection headers = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;